# Changing portal_normal.vm in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Right now I am using the default portal_normal.vm to display my page. I have made some changes to custom.css to give some look to the theme (JUst changed the colour of the background)

I have made some changes to the portal_normal.vm.

What if I want to give a complete different look to my page ? My answer is make changes to the portal_normal.vm page.

MY question is :

portal_normal.vm has some variables and stuff like:

```
 <html class="$root_css_class" dir="#language ("lang.dir")" lang="$w3c_language_id">
```

I would like to know where does portal_normal.vm get these values from? By values I mean values of variables like $root_css_class ? Usually velocity gets these values from a java class. So in liferay theme, from where does portal_normal.vm get these values from? Is it ok to change the portal_normal.vm file completely?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can change any thing in portal_noraml.vm file and you design your own look.

Here to change portal_normal.vm we will use theme. in _diff/templates   place classic theme portal_normal.vm and do changes.

All velocity variable are declared in init.vm file and we have another file called inti_custom.vm for declare our own velocity related variables.

Most of the velocity variables which required for portal already defined by liferay people we just use those.

Use  init_custom.vm in _diff/templates folder for custom velocity varibles.

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-web/docroot/html/themes/_unstyled/templates/init.vm

Most of the variables  already loaded by velocity engine so max we dont need to create new variables in velocity engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can create theme in liferay and provide customization in portal_normal.vm.

There is init.vm file where some of the variables are declared and also VelocityVariablesImpl.java is the class where vm variables are defined.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for the reply. I had created a new theme project and made changes to portal_normal.vm and custom.css but could not find VelocityVariablesImpl.java
Location of this file I searched and found it is:
portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/velocity/VelocityVariablesImpl.java

But I cannot find this file even after building services.
Can you please help?

Comment: And there is no init.vm file but init_custom.vm present in the theme project.

Comment: The init.vm is provided by the portal. You can see its contents here: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/html/themes/_unstyled/templates/init.vm In your theme, you can use the init_custom.vm to add your own variables before the templates are rendered

Comment: @jbalsas: Thanks jbalsas for the reply. So if I declare my variables to init_custom.vm they will be reflected in portal_normal.vm.. am I right?

Comment: correct: init_custom.vm is empty by default, but it's being used when your theme is processed. Anything you add in that file will be included in your other vm files.